# Handle settings of different types C++

Tags: c++, generics, export, settings, abstract

I don't really know how to explain the problem that I'm facing. This also makes it difficult for me to search the internet for answers. But I hope the issue will be clarified by the following code example that I made.

```
struct ISetting
{
    virtual void* GetValue() = 0;
};

template<typename T>
struct Setting : public ISetting
{
    T value;
    
    void* GetValue() 
    {
        return &value;
    }
};

struct Settings
{
    Setting<int> setting1;
    Setting<std::string> setting2;
    std::vector<ISetting*> allSettings;
    
    Settings()
    {
        allSettings.push_back(&setting1);
        allSettings.push_back(&setting2);
    }
    
};

int main()
{
    Settings settings;
    settings.setting1.value = 5;
    settings.setting2.value = "testing";
    
    for(int i=0; i<settings.allSettings.size(); i++)
    {
        void* value = settings.allSettings[i]->GetValue();
        
        printf("value = ...\n");
        
        
    }        
    return 0;
}
```

[Try this code](https://cpp.sh/?source=%23include+%3Ciostream%3E%0D%0A%23include+%3Cfunctional%3E%0D%0A%23include+%3Ctype_traits%3E%0D%0A%23include+%3Cstring%3E%0D%0A%23include+%3Cvector%3E%0D%0A%0D%0Astruct+ISetting%0D%0A%7B%0D%0A++++virtual+void*+GetValue()+%3D+0%3B%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Atemplate%3Ctypename+T%3E%0D%0Astruct+Setting+%3A+public+ISetting%0D%0A%7B%0D%0A++++T+value%3B%0D%0A++++%0D%0A++++void*+GetValue()+%0D%0A++++%7B%0D%0A++++++++return+%26value%3B%0D%0A++++%7D%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Astruct+Settings%0D%0A%7B%0D%0A++++Setting%3Cint%3E+setting1%3B%0D%0A++++Setting%3Cstd%3A%3Astring%3E+setting2%3B%0D%0A++++std%3A%3Avector%3CISetting*%3E+allSettings%3B%0D%0A++++%0D%0A++++Settings()%0D%0A++++%7B%0D%0A++++++++allSettings.push_back(%26setting1)%3B%0D%0A++++++++allSettings.push_back(%26setting2)%3B%0D%0A++++%7D%0D%0A++++%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aint+main()%0D%0A%7B%0D%0A++++Settings+settings%3B%0D%0A++++settings.setting1.value+%3D+5%3B%0D%0A++++settings.setting2.value+%3D+%22testing%22%3B%0D%0A++++%0D%0A++++for(int+i%3D0%3B+i%3Csettings.allSettings.size()%3B+i%2B%2B)%0D%0A++++%7B%0D%0A++++++++void*+value+%3D+settings.allSettings%5Bi%5D-%3EGetValue()%3B%0D%0A++++++++%0D%0A++++++++printf(%22value+%3D+...%5Cn%22)%3B%0D%0A++++++++%0D%0A++++++++%0D%0A++++%7D%0D%0A++++%0D%0A++++%0D%0A++++++++%0D%0A++++return+0%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A)

As you can see, I have a structure that contains settings. These settings can be of different types. Now I want to save those settings to flash (This runs on a micro controller) So I want to loop through all settings and write them accordingly. The problem is, I don't know the type of the setting since the type gets lost due to the interface. To simplify the issue I want to print the values of each setting to the output. Instead of writing to flash.

I did come up with one solution, but I'm not sure it this is the right way to go about it. The general idea is that the settings accept a visitor via its interface. The implemented setting then calls the appropiate function in the visitor with itself as varable. This visitor then knows what to do with this setting.

```
template<typename T>
struct Setting;

struct ISettingVisitor
{
    virtual void Visit(Setting<int>* setting) = 0;
    virtual void Visit(Setting<std::string>* setting) = 0;
};

struct ISetting
{
    virtual void Accept(ISettingVisitor* handler) = 0;
};

template<typename T>
struct Setting : public ISetting
{
    T value;
    
    void Accept(ISettingVisitor* handler)
    {
        handler->Visit(this);
    }
};


struct Settings
{
    Setting<int> setting1;
    Setting<std::string> setting2;
    std::vector<ISetting*> allSettings;
    
    Settings()
    {
        allSettings.push_back(&setting1);
        allSettings.push_back(&setting2);
    }
    
};

struct SettingsPrinter : public ISettingVisitor
{
    void Visit(Setting<int>* setting)           { printf("value = %d\n", setting->value); }
    void Visit(Setting<std::string>* setting)   { printf("value = %s\n", setting->value.c_str()); }
};

int main()
{
    Settings settings;
    settings.setting1.value = 5;
    settings.setting2.value = "testing";
    
    SettingsPrinter settingsPrinter;
    
    for(int i=0; i<settings.allSettings.size(); i++)
    {
        settings.allSettings[i]->Accept(&settingsPrinter);        
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

[Try this code](https://cpp.sh/?source=%23include+%3Ciostream%3E%0D%0A%23include+%3Cfunctional%3E%0D%0A%23include+%3Ctype_traits%3E%0D%0A%23include+%3Cstring%3E%0D%0A%23include+%3Cvector%3E%0D%0A%0D%0Atemplate%3Ctypename+T%3E%0D%0Astruct+Setting%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Astruct+ISettingVisitor%0D%0A%7B%0D%0A++++virtual+void+Visit(Setting%3Cint%3E*+setting)+%3D+0%3B%0D%0A++++virtual+void+Visit(Setting%3Cstd%3A%3Astring%3E*+setting)+%3D+0%3B%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Astruct+ISetting%0D%0A%7B%0D%0A++++virtual+void+Accept(ISettingVisitor*+handler)+%3D+0%3B%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Atemplate%3Ctypename+T%3E%0D%0Astruct+Setting+%3A+public+ISetting%0D%0A%7B%0D%0A++++T+value%3B%0D%0A++++%0D%0A++++void+Accept(ISettingVisitor*+handler)%0D%0A++++%7B%0D%0A++++++++handler-%3EVisit(this)%3B%0D%0A++++%7D%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Astruct+Settings%0D%0A%7B%0D%0A++++Setting%3Cint%3E+setting1%3B%0D%0A++++Setting%3Cstd%3A%3Astring%3E+setting2%3B%0D%0A++++std%3A%3Avector%3CISetting*%3E+allSettings%3B%0D%0A++++%0D%0A++++Settings()%0D%0A++++%7B%0D%0A++++++++allSettings.push_back(%26setting1)%3B%0D%0A++++++++allSettings.push_back(%26setting2)%3B%0D%0A++++%7D%0D%0A++++%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Astruct+SettingsPrinter+%3A+public+ISettingVisitor%0D%0A%7B%0D%0A++++void+Visit(Setting%3Cint%3E*+setting)+++++++++++%7B+printf(%22value+%3D+%25d%5Cn%22%2C+setting-%3Evalue)%3B+%7D%0D%0A++++void+Visit(Setting%3Cstd%3A%3Astring%3E*+setting)+++%7B+printf(%22value+%3D+%25s%5Cn%22%2C+setting-%3Evalue.c_str())%3B+%7D%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aint+main()%0D%0A%7B%0D%0A++++Settings+settings%3B%0D%0A++++settings.setting1.value+%3D+5%3B%0D%0A++++settings.setting2.value+%3D+%22testing%22%3B%0D%0A++++%0D%0A++++SettingsPrinter+settingsPrinter%3B%0D%0A++++%0D%0A++++for(int+i%3D0%3B+i%3Csettings.allSettings.size()%3B+i%2B%2B)%0D%0A++++%7B%0D%0A++++++++settings.allSettings%5Bi%5D-%3EAccept(%26settingsPrinter)%3B++++++++%0D%0A++++%7D%0D%0A++++%0D%0A++++return+0%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A)

Lets say I want to export the settings to a JSON format. This will be something along the lines of:

```
struct JSONExporter : public ISettingVisitor
{
    JSON* json = NULL;
    
    void Visit(Setting<int>* setting)           { json->AddInt(setting->name, setting->value); }
    void Visit(Setting<std::string>* setting)   { json->AddString(setting->name, setting->value); }

    std::string Export(Settings* settings)
    {
        json = new JSON();
        
        for(int i=0; i<settings.allSettings.size(); i++)
        {
            settings.allSettings[i]->Accept(this);        
        }
        
        
        std::string result = json->ToString();
        delete json;
        return result;
    }    
};
```

I quess this can work, but I'm not sure if a more streamlined solution exists.

---

Maybe a bit of a side question:

Is it possible to define the settings object in such a way that you cannot forget to add the settings to the list. Something along the lines of this:

```
struct Settings
{
    MyIterableThing allSettings
    {
        Setting<int> setting1;
        Setting<std::string> setting2;
    };

    Settings()
    {

    }
    
};


void main()
{
    Settings settings;
    settings.setting1.value = 5;

    for (auto& it : settings.allSettings) 
    {
        //Do something
    }
}
```

Comment: Nope, this is as streamlined as it gets. You're on the right track.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the verification

Answer (score 0):

Instead of what's essential a vector of void pointers, you can use a tuple with your actual types:

```
template<typename T>
struct Setting {
    T value;
    
    Setting(T const& val) : value{val} {}
    
    // More setting related things...
};

struct Settings {
    Setting<int> setting1;
    Setting<std::string> setting2;
    // Assuming we absolutely need raw pointers outside this example.
    //  Otherwise I'd use smart pointers.
    std::tuple<Setting<int>*, Setting<std::string>*> allSettings;
    
    // By supplying our own constructor we've implicitly deleted the
    //  default constructor. Creating a Settings now requires specifying
    //  initial values through this constructor.
    Settings(int s1, std::string s2)
        : setting1{s1}, setting2{s2}, allSettings{&s1, &s2} {}
    
    // More allSettings related things...
};

int main() {
    auto settings = Settings{5, "testing"};
    
    // You can iterate though a std::tuple without C++17's std::for_each,
    //  but it requires some ugly design pattern.
    std::for_each(
        settings.allSettings, 
        // Instead of a templated lambda we could use a named
        //  function, as long as it's templated/has overloads for
        //  int and std::string.
        [](auto const& setting) {
            std::cout << setting->value << "\n";
        }
    );
       
    // In C++ and C99, main will return 0 if you don't specify anything.
}
```